# Is it possible to scan for low energy devices in an IOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Assuming the handset is LE compatible, and Bluetooth is of course enabled, is it possible to scan (no pairing required) low-energy bluetooth devices from inside an app? That is, I want the app to check for devices every 30 seconds, say, and show a list of UUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks David, had a good look and it looks promising. The reason I asked is that i'll have to invest in a BLE iOS device for this project, and wanted to be certain this is do-able with no API restrictions.